# SQL 'If and statement'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to augment a post translational file so that the product names in the file such that first column of example is changed to a consistent text format:

```
"PRODUCT1 1000MG" >> "PRODUCT 1 1000 MG"

"PRODUCT 2 1500MG" >> "PRODUCT 2 1500 MG"

"PRODUCT3 PLATED 200MG"  >> "PRODUCT 3 PLATED 200 MG"
```

And so on, with approx 50 lines of different products to be queried. The only thing I can think of is a complex nested `IF` statement ....  ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could make a script using code plus mysql, then you could use a regular expresion to rebuild the text. In your case, use it to add a space before and after a set of numbers.

Comment: The answer depends heavily on the 'source' format that your product names follow. Are there any patterns they follow? If they are unpredictable you'll never be able to update all of them.

Comment: I agree with Jan. This is merely a data issue and there doesn't seem to be a general logic to apply.

Comment: I was commenting on what was provided, but even if the data is more varied there is usually a better solution. A question for you is, how did the data in this column get aggregated? Was it a concatenation of other fields? For example: product_name, product_id, size (in MG)? If so maybe the better solution is to re-aggregate the other column data and just replace the data you have.

Comment: You can avoid the nested IF mess with a stored function or an external application/script. Which one will be better depends on how complex your processing is going to be and how good you are at MySQL's procedural SQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add tables you could use a *translation table* and an *update with join*:

```
oldval                  newval
"PRODUCT1 1000MG"       "PRODUCT 1 1000 MG"
"PRODUCT 2 1500MG"      "PRODUCT 2 1500 MG"
"PRODUCT3 PLATED 200MG" "PRODUCT 3 PLATED 200 MG"
```

The query would look somehow like this:

```
UPDATE tab
  SET val = t.newval
  FROM MyTable tab
    INNER JOIN Transl t ON t.oldval = tab.val
```

Comment: The data originates as a complete text entry into a catalog.  ie. not concatenation or any other process.  Moving forward, text entries will  eventually be consistent (as products 'drop off') and further augmentation not required.